# How to call listener in another function in android

Tags: android, function, call

I Have this code

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {        
     if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {    
         Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);    

         Random r=new Random();    
         int i1=(r.nextInt(500) +4000);    

         v.vibrate(i1);    
   }    
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);    
}
```

and I want to call this listener in another class and another function. How should I call it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a class who implements your listener

```
public class MyListener implements OnClickListener {

    private Context context;

    public MyListener(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "just a test", 2000).show();
    }
}
```

And in your activity:

```
public class ListenerTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new MyListener(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new class called `MyUtils` for example and create a `static public` method that does the vibrating stuff. Then, call this static method from your listeners.

Like:

```
public class MyUtils {
    static public void vibrate(Context context) {
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);    

        Random r=new Random();    
        int i1=(r.nextInt(500) +4000);    

        v.vibrate(i1);    
    }
}
```

and:

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {        
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {    
        MyUtils.vibrate(this);
    }    
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);    
}
```